# Unable to close file because the last block does not have enough number of replicas

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, block, hdfs

From the error message it is quite obvious that, there was a problem in saving a replica of a particular block related to a file. The reason might be, there was a problem in accessing a data node to save a particular block(replica of a block).
Please refer below for the complete log:

I found another user "huasanyelao" - https://stackoverflow.com/users/987275/huasanyelao also had a similar exception/problem but the use case was different.

Now, how do we solve these kind of problems? I understand that there is no fixed solution to handle in all scenarios. 
1. What is the immediate step I need to take to fix errors of this kind? 
2. If there are jobs for which I'm not monitoring the log at that time. What approaches do I need to take to fix such issues.

P.S: Apart from fixing Network or Access Issues, what other approaches should I follow.

**Error Log:**

```
*15/04/10 11:21:13 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://your-name-node/ws/v1/timeline/
15/04/10 11:21:14 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at your-name-node/xxx.xx.xxx.xx:0000
15/04/10 11:21:34 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:29)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:512)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1516)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1272)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:525)
15/04/10 11:21:40 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not complete /user/xxxxx/.staging/job_11111111111_1212/job.jar retrying...
15/04/10 11:21:46 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not complete /user/xxxxx/.staging/job_11111111111_1212/job.jar retrying...
15/04/10 11:21:59 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /user/xxxxx/.staging/job_11111111111_1212
Error occured in MapReduce process:
java.io.IOException: Unable to close file because the last block does not have enough number of replicas.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.completeFile(DFSOutputStream.java:2132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.close(DFSOutputStream.java:2100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:103)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1903)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1871)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1836)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyJar(JobSubmitter.java:286)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
        at com.xxx.xxx.xxxx.driver.GenerateMyFormat.runMyExtract(GenerateMyFormat.java:222)
        at com.xxx.xxx.xxxx.driver.GenerateMyFormat.run(GenerateMyFormat.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at com.xxx.xxx.xxxx.driver.GenerateMyFormat.main(GenerateMyFormat.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)*
```

Comment: just curious, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @robert towne: I couldn't replicate this again. Do you have a defined flow or steps to replicate this issue?

Comment: No, I couldn't replicate this again. I'm assuming this to be a network related issue.

Comment: Not sure, but it sounds like [HDFS-11486](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-11486), which has been fixed in later versions of Hadoop.

Answer (score 2):

We had similar issue. Its primarily attributed to dfs.namenode.handler.count  was not enough. Increasing that may help in some small clusters but it is because of DOS issue where nameNode couldn't handle no. of connections or RPC call and your Pending deletion blocks will grow humongous. Validate the hdfs audit logs and see  any mass deletion happening or other hdfs actions and match with the jobs which might be overwhelming NN . Stoping those tasks will help HDFS to recover.